# How to make MySQL utilize available system resources, or find "the real problem"?

Tags: mysql

This is a MySQL 5.0.26 server, running on SuSE Enterprise 10. This may be a Serverfault question.

The web user interface that uses these particular queries (below) is showing sometimes **30+**, even up to 120+ **seconds** at the worst, to generate the pages involved.

On development, when the queries are run alone, they take up to 20 seconds on the first run (with no query cache enabled) but anywhere from 2 to 7 seconds after that - I assume because the tables and indexes involved have been placed into ram.

From what I can tell, the longest load times are caused by **Read/Update Locking**. These are **MyISAM** tables. So it looks like a long update comes in, followed by a couple 7 second queries, and they're just adding up. And I'm fine with that explanation.

What I'm not fine with is that **MySQL doesn't appear to be utilizing the hardware it's on**, and while the bottleneck seems to be the database, *I can't understand why*.

I would say "throw more hardware at it", but *we did* and it doesn't appear to have changed the situation. Viewing a 'top' during the slowest times never shows much cpu or memory utilization by `mysqld`, as if the server is having no trouble at all - but then, why are the queries taking so long?

### How can I make MySQL use the crap out of this hardware, or find out what I'm doing wrong?

**Extra Details:**

On the "Memory Health" tab in the MySQL Administrator (for Windows), the Key Buffer is less than 1/8th used - so all the indexes should be in RAM. I can provide a screen shot of any graphs that might help.

So desperate to fix this issue. Suffice it to say, there is legacy code "generating" these queries, and they're pretty much stuck the way they are. I have tried every combination of Indexes on the tables involved, but any suggestions are welcome.

Here's the current Create Table statement from development (the 'experimental' key I have added, seems to help *a little*, for the example query only):

```
CREATE TABLE `registration_task` (                                                       
    `id` varchar(36) NOT NULL default '',                                                  
    `date_entered` datetime NOT NULL default '0000-00-00 00:00:00',                        
    `date_modified` datetime NOT NULL default '0000-00-00 00:00:00',                       
    `assigned_user_id` varchar(36) default NULL,                                           
    `modified_user_id` varchar(36) default NULL,                                           
    `created_by` varchar(36) default NULL,                                                 
    `name` varchar(80) NOT NULL default '',                                                
    `status` varchar(255) default NULL,                                                    
    `date_due` date default NULL,                                                          
    `time_due` time default NULL,                                                          
    `date_start` date default NULL,                                                        
    `time_start` time default NULL,                                                        
    `parent_id` varchar(36) NOT NULL default '',                                           
    `priority` varchar(255) NOT NULL default '9',                                          
    `description` text,                                                                    
    `order_number` int(11) default '1',                                                    
    `task_number` int(11) default NULL,                                                    
    `depends_on_id` varchar(36) default NULL,                                              
    `milestone_flag` varchar(255) default NULL,                                            
    `estimated_effort` int(11) default NULL,                                               
    `actual_effort` int(11) default NULL,                                                  
    `utilization` int(11) default '100',                                                   
    `percent_complete` int(11) default '0',                                                
    `deleted` tinyint(1) NOT NULL default '0',                                             
    `wf_task_id` varchar(36) default '0',                                                  
    `reg_field` varchar(8) default '',                                                     
    `date_offset` int(11) default '0',                                                     
    `date_source` varchar(10) default '',                                                  
    `date_completed` date default '0000-00-00',                                            
    `completed_id` varchar(36) default NULL,                                               
    `original_name` varchar(80) default NULL,                                              
    PRIMARY KEY  (`id`),                                                                   
    KEY `idx_reg_task_p` (`deleted`,`parent_id`),                                          
    KEY `By_Assignee` (`assigned_user_id`,`deleted`),                                      
    KEY `status_assignee` (`status`,`deleted`),                                            
    KEY `experimental` (`deleted`,`status`,`assigned_user_id`,`parent_id`,`date_due`)  
    ) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
```

And one of the ridiculous queries in question:

```
SELECT 
    users.user_name   
    assigned_user_name, 
    registration.FIELD001 parent_name, 
    registration_task.status status,
    registration_task.date_modified date_modified,
    registration_task.date_due date_due, 
    registration.FIELD240 assigned_wf,
    if(LENGTH(registration_task.description)>0,1,0) has_description,
    registration_task.* 
FROM 
    registration_task LEFT JOIN users ON registration_task.assigned_user_id=users.id 
    LEFT JOIN registration ON registration_task.parent_id=registration.id 
where 
    (registration_task.status != 'Completed' AND registration.FIELD001 LIKE '%' 
       AND registration_task.name LIKE '%' AND registration.FIELD060 LIKE 'GN001472%') 
    AND  registration_task.deleted=0  
ORDER BY date_due asc LIMIT 0,20;
```

#### my.cnf - '[mysqld]' section.

```
[mysqld]
port = 3306
socket  = /var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock
skip-locking
key_buffer = 384M
max_allowed_packet = 100M
table_cache = 2048 
sort_buffer_size = 2M 
net_buffer_length = 100M 
read_buffer_size = 2M 
read_rnd_buffer_size = 160M 
myisam_sort_buffer_size = 128M
query_cache_size = 16M
query_cache_limit = 1M
```

#### EXPLAIN above query, without additional index

:

```
       
+----+-------------+-------------------+--------+--------------------------------+----------------+---------+------------------------------------------------+---------+-----------------------------+
| id | select_type | table             | type   | possible_keys                  | key            | key_len | ref                                            | rows    | Extra                       |
+----+-------------+-------------------+--------+--------------------------------+----------------+---------+------------------------------------------------+---------+-----------------------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | registration_task | ref    | idx_reg_task_p,status_assignee | idx_reg_task_p | 1       | const                                          | 1067354 | Using where; Using filesort |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | registration      | eq_ref | PRIMARY,gbl                    | PRIMARY        | 8       | sugarcrm401.registration_task.parent_id        |       1 | Using where                 |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | users             | ref    | PRIMARY                        | PRIMARY        | 38      | sugarcrm401.registration_task.assigned_user_id |       1 |                             |
+----+-------------+-------------------+--------+--------------------------------+----------------+---------+------------------------------------------------+---------+-----------------------------+
```

#### EXPLAIN above query, with 'experimental' index:

```
       
+----+-------------+-------------------+--------+-----------------------------------------------------------+------------------+---------+------------------------------------------------+--------+-----------------------------+
| id | select_type | table             | type   | possible_keys                                             | key              | key_len | ref                                            | rows   | Extra                       |
+----+-------------+-------------------+--------+-----------------------------------------------------------+------------------+---------+------------------------------------------------+--------+-----------------------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | registration_task | range  | idx_reg_task_p,status_assignee,NewIndex1,tcg_experimental | tcg_experimental | 259     | NULL                                           | 103345 | Using where; Using filesort |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | registration      | eq_ref | PRIMARY,gbl                                               | PRIMARY          | 8       | sugarcrm401.registration_task.parent_id        |      1 | Using where                 |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | users             | ref    | PRIMARY                                                   | PRIMARY          | 38      | sugarcrm401.registration_task.assigned_user_id |      1 |                             |
+----+-------------+-------------------+--------+-----------------------------------------------------------+------------------+---------+------------------------------------------------+--------+-----------------------------+
```

#### SHOW INDEXES FROM registration_task;

```
mysql> SHOW INDEXES FROM registration_task;
+-------------------+------------+------------------+--------------+------------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+
| Table             | Non_unique | Key_name         | Seq_in_index | Column_name      | Collation | Cardinality | Sub_part | Packed | Null | Index_type | Comment |
+-------------------+------------+------------------+--------------+------------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+
| registration_task |          0 | PRIMARY          |            1 | id               | A         |     1445612 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |
| registration_task |          1 | idx_reg_task_p   |            1 | deleted          | A         |           2 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |
| registration_task |          1 | idx_reg_task_p   |            2 | parent_id        | A         |       57824 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |
| registration_task |          1 | By_Assignee      |            1 | assigned_user_id | A         |        5295 |     NULL | NULL   | YES  | BTREE      |         |
| registration_task |          1 | By_Assignee      |            2 | deleted          | A         |        5334 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |
| registration_task |          1 | status_assignee  |            1 | status           | A         |          18 |     NULL | NULL   | YES  | BTREE      |         |
| registration_task |          1 | status_assignee  |            2 | deleted          | A         |          23 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |
| registration_task |          1 | NewIndex1        |            1 | deleted          | A         |           2 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |
| registration_task |          1 | NewIndex1        |            2 | assigned_user_id | A         |        5334 |     NULL | NULL   | YES  | BTREE      |         |
| registration_task |          1 | NewIndex1        |            3 | parent_id        | A         |      180701 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |
| registration_task |          1 | tcg_experimental |            1 | date_due         | A         |        1919 |     NULL | NULL   | YES  | BTREE      |         |
| registration_task |          1 | tcg_experimental |            2 | deleted          | A         |        3191 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |
| registration_task |          1 | tcg_experimental |            3 | status           | A         |        8503 |     NULL | NULL   | YES  | BTREE      |         |
| registration_task |          1 | tcg_experimental |            4 | assigned_user_id | A         |       53541 |     NULL | NULL   | YES  | BTREE      |         |
| registration_task |          1 | tcg_experimental |            5 | parent_id        | A         |      722806 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |
+-------------------+------------+------------------+--------------+------------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+

15 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

### Solution?

I think I may have solved the problem, that to some will seem *so embarrassingly obvious*, but was somehow overlooked until now: The definition of `registration.id`, is:

```
`id` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL auto_increment
```

While the `registration_task.parent_id` (FK to `registration.id`) was:

```
`parent_id` varchar(36) NOT NULL
```

Changing this via:

```
alter table `sugarcrm401`.`registration_task` change `parent_id` `parent_id` bigint(20) UNSIGNED NOT NULL;
```

... causes the EXPLAIN to show only **25** rows examined, where it was earlier **651,903**, and **103,345** at it's best when forcing crazy indexing.

Had I posted the table definition of the `registration` table, I'm sure someone might have spotted it. I'm going to verify this and post followup after the weekend.

Comment: I know that the table definition and queries here look a bit WTF-y, or insane. *I agree*. I didn't do it, but I *have to fix it*. It came with the job.

Comment: Ha!  You may (or may not) find this humorous.
http://forum.percona.com/index.php/mv/msg/843/3328/

Comment: I *do* find that humorous, and let me tell you why: The second-to-last post on that thread is from 2008. The most recent post, pointing out the same as I have discovered, is from April 2010. I wish I'd have gotten to "reply to a thread..." email, because **I am** 'anon_login'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer to a majority of the problem was as posted in my edit:

The definition of `registration.id`, is:

```
`id` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL auto_increment
```

While the `registration_task.parent_id` (FK to `registration.id`) was:

```
`parent_id` varchar(36) NOT NULL
```

Changing this via:

```
alter table `sugarcrm401`.`registration_task` change `parent_id` `parent_id` bigint(20) UNSIGNED NOT NULL;
```

... causes the EXPLAIN to show only **25** rows examined, where it was earlier **651,903**, and **103,345** at it's best when forcing crazy indexing.

Had I posted the table definition of the `registration` table, I'm sure someone might have spotted it.

---

This, however, didn't solve the problem completely. I'm sure I'm leaving out some detail, but this project is far behind me at this point. Thanks so much for all of your time and answers!

Answer (score 1):

When you have a query that says != it's invariably going to be slow. And note that the index is not being used on that part of the query even though the status field is on two different indexes!

You don't want to have a varchar(255) field fully indexed and having it as part of two different keys is going to make your updates very very slow. Having a total of five indexes is just going to add to the mess. If you are doing any select at the same moment that an update is happening, it's really going to take a long time as you have already seen.

What you might want to do is to index only a small section of your 255 character field. Better still, you might want use an integer (statusCode) instead of status here. That will speed things up a great deal.

Having more memory or more CPU is not going to help here. Having an extra hard drive give you a 20 - 30% speed boost. But you can make the same query complete in less than a second by just reorganizing your indexes.

Comment: As for changing 'status', unfortunately I can't change the fields themselves, or what's contained in them. I'm very, very, very interested in specific index organization suggestions. If I could get this query run-time down to less than a second by changing indexes alone, I'll send you a shoebox of goodies in the mail!

Comment: Well you can start off by dropping all the indexes that are not being used. The explain shows what's being used and what's not being used.
That will speed up the inserts/updates, which means your select queries no longer have to wait on them to finish. That itself will give you a big boost.

Comment: Have you tried :

WHERE  registration_task.deleted=0 AND (registration_task.status != 'Completed' AND registration.FIELD001 LIKE '%' 
       AND registration_task.name LIKE '%' AND registration.FIELD060 LIKE 'GN001472%')

Comment: The other indexes are all results of speeding up specific queries/joins in other places in the application. As for rearranging the WHERE, EXPLAIN changes the order of tables observed, but doesn't change indexes used, or number of rows scanned on the registration_task table, the only one scanning more than a single row. 

So if my writes are locking other reads, would moving to a replication Master-for-writes/Slave(s)-for-reads actually improve performance? How do the updates on a Slave work?

Comment: Replication could help, moving to Innodb also may help your performance.

Comment: Well, if the other indexes are needed for other queries. What you can do is to reduce the number of bytes indexes as I mentioned earlier.

For long char or varchar fields you only need to index the first 5-10 characters. You will get pretty much the same cardinality as an index on the whole 255 field.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to optimize this with proper Indexes.  As FractalizeR said, you need indexes on join columns, and columns in your Where statement.  Just adding them all to one Index will not solve your problem.  What indexes do you have on Registration?

Comment: Firstly, I've very carefully added fields in order of their use by the engine to the largest index you're seeing. I've not simply added "them all" to an index. There are other indexes on the primary table here as well. As for indexes on `registration`, there are a few, but my understanding is that MySQL will only use a single index during a query, and since a majority of the operations are done on the `registration_task` table, I was focusing there.

Comment: Sorry, did not mean to sound harsh, just reinforcing the point.  I was curious about the Registration table, as there maybe a way to optimize by restructuring your query.   You are using a Left Join, do you really want to display tasks that have no user or registration?

Comment: Well, as I mentioned in the giant wall of text, changing the queries around isn't much of an option, on account of them being automatically generated by the software. I think I may have found a solution, and have added yet-more-text to the wall above.

Answer (score 0):

Please post SHOW INDEXES result from your tables. Generic recommendation I can give just now is to:

- Add separate indexes on registration_task fields: assigned_user_id, parent_id, date_due
- Add index on registration.FIELD060
- Remove part of the query "AND registration.FIELD001 LIKE '%' AND registration_task.name LIKE '%'" - it is useless. % means any number of any chars

After that please post EXPLAIN again.

Comment: If I put `date_due` on the beginning of the 'experimental' index, explain considers, but doesn't use it at all, opting instead for the original `idx_reg_task_p` index. Do you have any specific recommendations on getting that to work?

Comment: I updated my comment. Please do as it said and report back. We'll see what we can do.

Comment: As for removing part of the query - it's automatically generated by this horrendous, frankenstein-like system. I'll split up indexes and re-EXPLAIN and get back to you.

Comment: I've added individual indexes which, as I expected, shows no difference in MySQLs preference of index to use - either idx_reg_task_p, or tcg_experimental if available. Also, there is already an index on the 'FIELD060', called 'gbl', which is in use and optimal, as you can see by the EXPLAIN results showing only 1 row examined for that table.